# Adding icon picture to Radio Button Box in Java

Tags: java, radio-button, icons

I'd like to replace the standard Java coffee mug picture on this simple radio button pane with an image. (I'm using a Mac).

I've used url method in dialog boxes, but can't figure it out on this one.
final ImageIcon MyImageName = new ImageIcon(new URL(...etc.))

```
    package TestEnvironment;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

    import FinalProject_PizzaHub.RadioButtonActionListener;

    public class RadioButtonTest 
    {
        static String Size;
        final JPanel panelSize = new JPanel();
final JRadioButton radioButtonSmall = new JRadioButton("Small");
final JRadioButton radioButtonMedium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
final JRadioButton radioButtonLarge = new JRadioButton("Large");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new RadioButtonTest();
    }

    public RadioButtonTest()
    {
panelSize.add(radioButtonSmall);
panelSize.add(radioButtonMedium);
panelSize.add(radioButtonLarge);

RadioButtonActionListener actionListener = new RadioButtonActionListener();
    radioButtonSmall.addActionListener(actionListener);
    radioButtonMedium.addActionListener(actionListener);
    radioButtonLarge.addActionListener(actionListener);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panelSize);

if (radioButtonSmall.isSelected())
    {Size = "Small";
    System.out.println("Size is small");}
if (radioButtonMedium.isSelected())
    {Size = "Medium";
    System.out.println("Size is medium");}
if (radioButtonLarge.isSelected())
    {Size = "Large";
    System.out.println("Size is Large");} 
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the application icon?

Comment: Pete, yes, I'm trying to replace the standard Java coffee cup that appears on dialog boxes (on a Mac) when nothing is specified.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a picture on this post, but I've save it here:
http://i162.photobucket.com/albums/t250/SheaJeff/JavaImages/radio.png

Comment: Are you trying this on a message box? Do you have any JFrame?

Comment: The code above is all I've got.

Comment: Okay. How to resolve the import `import FinalProject_PizzaHub.RadioButtonActionListener;`? and I hope you are running it as a java application.